# Proof Check of this Theorem in Metric Spaces

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I saw this question is asked previously but still the answer is not convincing to me. The theorem states that a sequence in the metric space $(\mathbb{R}^n,d_{l^1})$ converges if and only if it converges in $(\mathbb{R}^n, d_{l^2})$.

Proof for the second implication : Suppose $\lim_{k \to \infty} \sqrt{|x_1^{(k)}-x_1|^2+|x_2^{(k)}-x_2|^2+\cdots +|x_n^{(k)}-x_n|^2}=0$, i.e, the sequence $(x_1^{(k)},x_2^{(k)},\cdots, x_n^{(k)})_{k \to \infty}\to(x_1,x_2,\cdots, x_n)$

By the CS-inequality, $n{\sum a_i^2}\geq (\sum a_i)^2 $ so that $$\sqrt{|x_1^{(k)}-x_1|^2+|x_2^{(k)}-x_2|^2+\cdots +|x_n^{(k)}-x_n|^2} \geq \frac{|x_1^{(k)}-x_1|+\cdots + |x_n^{(k)}-x_n|}{n}\geq 0$$ and by the Squeeze Theorem $\frac{1}{n}\lim_{k \to \infty} ||x_1^{(k)}-x_1|+\cdots +|x_n^{(k)}-x_n||=0$ which gives the desired conclusion.

I would be thankful if you check this proof and also suggest whether i should start with metric spaces or abstract algebra thoroughly. Thanks.

Comment: Note : $d_{l^1}$ is the taxicab metric and $d_{l^2}$ is the Euclidean Metric in case it is not standard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$. As you said, by Cauchy-Scharz inequality for one side, and by looking a bit closer for the other side, one can show that
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{n}\|x\|_1 \leqslant \|x\|_2 \leqslant \sqrt{n}\|x\|_1
\end{align}
Say $(x_k)$ is a sequence and $x_{\infty}$ a point. Then
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{n}\|x_k-x_{\infty}\|_1 \leqslant \|x_k-x_{\infty}\|_2 \leqslant \sqrt{n}\|x_k-x_{\infty}\|_1
\end{align}
You can conclude from that the following 
\begin{align}
\|x_k-x_{\infty}\|_1 \to_{k\to\infty} 0 \iff \|x_k-x_{\infty}\|_2 \to_{k\to \infty} 0
\end{align}
That is, $(x_k)$ converges to $x_{\infty}$ in $d_1$ if and only if it converges to $x_{\infty}$ in $d_2$.

In fact, Riesz's theorem states that for a finite dimensional vector spaces, all norms are equivalent, so this is true for every distance defined by a norm in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Riesz Theorem sounds interesting... so thats true for all finite dimension spaces? Wow! Well, can you suggest whether do metric spaces in more detail or go for thorough abstract algebra?

Comment: For my level,i have completed Analysis by Tao and Bartle Sherbert(upto differentiability), so i now think what to do next - I want to do metric spaces and bit measure theory before touching Carothers' Analysis, but Abstract Algebra is too attractive.

Comment: This is particular for finite dimensional vector spaces with a metrics that comes from a norm! Not all metrics are constructed like that. There are many distances in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that are non-equivalent to the euclidean distance, but they do not come from a norm

Comment: @Dldier i see...

Comment: Topology of metric spaces is really interresting, but has barely nothing to do with abstract algebra. The case of normed vector spaces is a really particular one at the intersection of all these domains

Comment: thanks! :) Got work now.